# XCOM variable push is getting failed

Tags: airflow

In Airflow DAG, I am trying to write data in return.json and trying to push it. This task is getting failed randomly saying below error.

```
**{taskinstance.py:1455} ERROR - Unterminated string starting at: line 1**
```

Once I retry this task, it is getting successfully executed. I am not able to understand why some tasks are getting randomly failed in flow. Sometime in flow execution, none of the task are failing. Could someone please help me on this.

Comment: please post the code

Comment: Elad it is happening in Airflow DAG run, my code part is executing perfectly fine. Exception is coming only when I am using XCOM.

Comment: I would like to see the code to see if you are using XCOM correctly. Which version of Airflow are you using? Can you provide the full task log?